# Make JTextField semi-transparent

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, colors

The questions says it all really, I want the make the background of a JTextField semi-transparent and I am using a timer to make it flash.

So I have found that using the traditional textField.setBackground() yeilds a strange graphical glitch where with each flash the text field is darker than it should be. (see below)

[strange graphical glitch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyYge.png)

So after searching online I tried to override the paint method of the JTextField with the following code:

```
name = new JTextField(15) {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(this.getBackground());
            g.fillRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
            super.paintComponent(g);
        }
    };
```

Also, some recommended that I set the text field opaque boolean to false. This I did and to no avail, now there is not even any red flashing and I simply get this:

[fields with field.setOpaque(false);](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctSkC.png)

Just in case it helps, here is the code I am using to make the fields flash.

```
    public void flashField(JTextField field, Color flashColor, final int flashDelay, final int numberOfFlashes) {
    timers.add(new Timer(flashDelay, new ActionListener() {

        int counter = 0;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            counter++;
            if (counter % 2 == 0)
                field.setBackground(
                        new Color(flashColor.getRed(), flashColor.getBlue(), flashColor.getGreen(), 50));
            else
                field.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

            if (counter == (numberOfFlashes * 2) + 1) {
                ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
            }

            field.repaint();
        }
    }));

    timers.get(timers.size() - 1).start();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So after searching online I tried to override the paint method
>
> Also, some recommended that I set the text field opaque boolean to false.

Well you need to do both at the same time. Something like:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel()
{
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor( getBackground() );
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
};
panel.setOpaque(false); // background of parent will be painted first
panel.setBackground( new Color(255, 0, 0, 20) );
frame.add(panel);
```

Check out [Background With Transparency](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for why this is necessary and for a simple reusable solution that you can use on any component without doing custom painting every time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an adapted code where Textfield keeps on flashing every 200ms and is transparent.

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TransparentTextFieldExample {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TransparentTextFieldExample();
}

public TransparentTextFieldExample() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            }

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            TransparentTextField ttf = new TransparentTextField("Some text!", 20);
            panel.add(ttf);
            frame.add(panel);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            flashField(ttf, Color.RED, 1, 20);
        }
    });

}

public void flashField(JTextField field, java.awt.Color flashColor, final int flashDelay, final int numberOfFlashes) {

    Timer tm = new Timer(flashDelay, new ActionListener() {

        int counter = 0;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (counter % 2 == 0) {
                field.setBackground(flashColor);
            } else {
                field.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            }
            if (counter == (numberOfFlashes * 2) + 1) {
                System.out.println("Inside");
                //((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                //  break;
            }

            field.repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200l);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
            counter++;
        }
    });
    tm.start();

}

public class TransparentTextField extends JTextField {

    public TransparentTextField(String text) {
        super(text);
        init();
    }

    public TransparentTextField(int columns) {
        super(columns);
        init();
    }

    public TransparentTextField(String text, int columns) {
        super(text, columns);
        init();
    }

    protected void init() {
        setOpaque(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive(0.5f));
        super.paint(g2d);
        g2d.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.setColor(getBackground());
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        super.paintComponent(g2d);
        g2d.dispose();
    }

}
}
```